# Indexing through a pandas data frame with date time timestamp

Tags: pandas, finance

```
   >>> df1
                    AAPL       GOOG 

    Date                                                      
    2016-03-01  0.013422  -0.321900
    2016-03-02 -0.012341  -0.000800 
    2016-03-03 -0.000772   0.055500
    2016-03-07 -0.413103  -0.009555

   >>> df2
                        NFLX         FB 
        Date                                                      
        2016-03-01  0.013422  -0.321900
        2016-03-02 -0.012341  -0.000800 
        2016-03-03 -0.000772   0.055500
        2016-03-07 -0.413103  -0.009555
```

I want to be able to index with timestamps. But it gives me an error. For example if I want to do:

```
df1['2016-03-01']
```

this works and returns the first line of df1.
But if i do:

```
df1[df2.index[0]]
```

This does not work and returns and error. I'm coding something that is iterating dates and I'm struggling to find a solution. Please help

Comment: Please report the exact error you are getting.

Comment: if this works : df1['2016-03-01']  then '2016-03-01' is in the columns

Answer (score 1):

> Make your dfs

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2016-03-01","2016-03-02","2016-03-03","2016-03-07"],
                   "AAPL": [0.013422,-0.012341,-0.000772,-0.413103],
                   "GOOG": [-0.321900,-0.000800,0.055500,-0.009555]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2016-03-18"],
                    "NFLX": [0.23525],
                    "FB": [-0.28942]})

# set date to datetime
df1["Date"],df2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"]),pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"])

# set Date as index
df1,df2 = df1.set_index("Date"),df2.set_index("Date")

# output1
>>> df1
                AAPL       GOOG 

Date                                                      
2016-03-01  0.013422  -0.321900
2016-03-02 -0.012341  -0.000800 
2016-03-03 -0.000772   0.055500
2016-03-07 -0.413103  -0.009555

# output2
>>> df2
                NFLX       FB 

Date        
2016-03-01  0.235250    -0.289420
```

> Add rows by index from df2 to df1

```
for i,j in enumerate(df1.index):
    df2 = df2.append(df1.iloc[[i]],sort=True)

>>> df2
             AAPL       FB      GOOG      NFLX
Date                
2016-03-18  NaN     -0.28942    NaN     0.23525
2016-03-01  0.013422    NaN     -0.321900   NaN
2016-03-02  -0.012341   NaN     -0.000800   NaN
2016-03-03  -0.000772   NaN     0.055500    NaN
2016-03-07  -0.413103   NaN     -0.009555   NaN
```

Comment: I should've been a bit more specific. So df2 actually has one date.... let's say the first date (2016-03-01) and df1 has many many dates. I'm actually trying to create a new row in df2 by taking dates in df1. So i'm creating a new row by doing df2.loc[df1.index[i]] where i is a for-loop (for i in len(df1.index))

Comment: Let me update my answer and tell me what you think.